# How to get Average rating in entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities

Hi I have below code as

```
var query = (from R in db.Registrations
            join c in db.Campus
            on R.CampusId equals c.CampusId
            from tsr in db.TutorStudentRequests.Where(t => t.TutorId == R.RegistrationId).DefaultIfEmpty()
            where R.UserTypeId == 2 && tsr.StatusId!=3
            orderby R.Name ascending
            select new
            {
                RegistrationId = R.RegistrationId,
                Name = R.Name,
                Email = R.Email,
                Phone = R.Phone,
                Password = c.CampusName,
                IsGPA = R.IsGPA,
                IsActive = R.IsActive,
                StripeId = R.StripeId,
                CreatedOn = R.CreatedOn,
                UserTypeId =tsr.StudentReviewRating
            })
        .ToList();
```

I have Registration table having single row and I also have another table TutorStudentRequests which have multiple rows.  How can I get average of column name StudentReviewRating present in TutorStudentRequests table?

Structure may be seem as:

**Registration Table**

```
RegistrationId   Name   Email 
   1             abc    abc@gmail.com
   2             xyz    xyz@gmail.com
```

**TutorStudentRequests  Table**

```
Id  TutorId(RegistrationId of F.k.)   StudentReviewRating
 1    1                                    5
 2    1                                    2
 3    1                                    1
 4    2                                    3
```

I want UserTypeId data as average of StudentReviewRating for each TutorId

**Tried**

```
var query = (from R in db.Registrations
        join c in db.Campus
        on R.CampusId equals c.CampusId
        from tsr in db.TutorStudentRequests.Where(t => t.TutorId == R.RegistrationId).DefaultIfEmpty()
        where R.UserTypeId == 2 && tsr.StatusId != 3
        group R by new
        {
            R.RegistrationId,
            R.Name,
            R.Email,
            R.Phone,
            c.CampusName,
            R.IsGPA,
            R.IsActive,
            R.StripeId,
            R.CreatedOn,                      
        } into groupings
        select new
        {
            RegistrationId = groupings.Key.RegistrationId,
            Name = groupings.Key.Name,
            Email = groupings.Key.Email,
            Phone = groupings.Key.Phone,
            Password = groupings.Key.CampusName,
            IsGPA = groupings.Key.IsGPA,
            IsActive = groupings.Key.IsActive,
            StripeId = groupings.Key.StripeId,
            CreatedOn = groupings.Key.CreatedOn,
            Average = groupings.Average(p=>Convert.ToDecimal(p.StudentReviewRating))
        });
```

But it is saying Registration does not contain a definition for 'StudentReviewRating'..

What is wrong?

Comment: Why `entity-framework` tag if you are writing queries with joins by hand? Learn to use *navigation properties* and the query in question will be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

how about grouping by tutor, calculate the average as total ratings/number of ratings

```
var query = from request in data
            group request by request.TutorId into groupings
            let total = groupings.Sum(p=>p.StudentReviewRating)
            let number = groupings.Count()
            let average = (decimal)total/number
            select new 
            {
                TutorId = groupings.Key,
                Summary = new 
                {
                    Total = total,
                    Number = number,
                    Average = average
                }
            }
```

and results would look like this for the given test case

```
TutorId Summary
1   Total   8
    Number  3
    Average 2.66
2   Total   3
    Number  1
    Average 3
```

**Edit** extra joins and extended group by

```
var query = from registration in registrations
            join request in requests 
                on registration.RegistrationId equals request.TutorId
            group request by new 
            {
                registration.RegistrationId,
                registration.Name, 
                request.TutorId,
            } into groupings
            select new 
            {
                RegistrationId = groupings.Key.RegistrationId,
                TutorId = groupings.Key.TutorId,
                Average = groupings.Average(p=>p.StudentReviewRating)
            }
```

Comment: can you make it more clear using my query, In my query I had added left join and inner join both

Comment: i've added the outcome based on your test case

Comment: Can u see my updates, Why I am not getting my record present in Registrations table

Comment: once you group by R is no longer available, but g is, see my example where i use groupings

Comment: Can u use my query and update your answer using my query

Comment: As I had used joins it seems to be complicated for me

Comment: it has nothing to do with the joins, it's about the grouping, use select g.Key.RegistrationId and g.Average(...)

Comment: please use joins in your query like this  from R in db.Registrations
        join c in db.Campus
        on R.CampusId equals c.CampusId
        from tsr in db.TutorStudentRequests.Where(t => t.TutorId == R.RegistrationId).DefaultIfEmpty()

Comment: you are using only one table which make query more easy, I want to get query using joins, and also see I want to retrive multiple columns that exist in Registration table

Comment: you just need to extend the group by with whatever you need and project on whatever columns are relevant (check my edits)

Comment: Can u please give an example while updating your answer as I am new

Comment: sure, play around with this https://gist.github.com/dandohotaru/d9e0659cb63514ac2cb3d8a06bc86769, remove all the noise from your examples when learning something new

Comment: Please see my updated question, I am facing 1 issue that I am not able to write UserTypeId = groupings.Average(p => p.StudentReviewRating)

Comment: you want to calculate the average based on grouping some data but you should not include the calculated field in the group by, otherwise what is the point of the grouping?

Comment: see I had change the code, still issue is coming from my end

Comment: remove tsr.anything from grouping. moreover t.TutorId == R.RegistrationId according to your sample and you already have RegistrationId in the group by

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161468/discussion-between-xtremcool-and-dan-dohotaru).

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can Use this to have all you want about math here 
https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/